# ASP.Net download file from folder based on the file path saved in sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, directory

i am uploading the file in folder and saving the path with file name in ms sql database. I want to download those files from that folder based on the path saved in sql database for the particular record. I searched the web but getting the example which are saving the images, files etc. in database not folder.
Please help how to download files from folder if path is saved in database.

```
//Upload files
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
 {
 string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);         
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("upload/" + FileName));          
 String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
 .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
 string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles (Name, FilePath)" +
 " values(@FileName, @FilePath)";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "upload/" + FileName);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.Connection = con;
 try
 {
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Response.Write(ex.Message);               
 }
 finally
 {               
 con.Close();
 con.Dispose();
 }
 }
 }

// show data in grid
public void shofile2()
 {
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
 ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
 string strQuery = "select * from tblFiles where UnqId = '" + UnqId1.Text + "'";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.Connection = con;
 try
 {
 con.Open();
 sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
 sda.Fill(dt);
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Response.Write(ex.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
 con.Close();
 sda.Dispose();
 con.Dispose();
 }
 }

// just trying for download 
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
 {
 con.Close();
 }
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblFiles", con);
 SqlDataReader DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (DR1.Read())
 {
 //Label40.Visible = true;
 //Label40.Text = DR1.GetValue(5).ToString();
 string filePath = DR1.GetValue(2).ToString();
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
 Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
 Response.End();
 }  
 }
```

//table

```
CREATE TABLE  dbo . tblFiles (
 id   int  IDENTITY(8184,1) NOT NULL,
 Name   varchar (500) NULL,
 FilePath   varchar (500) NULL,
 ContentType   varchar (500) NULL,
 Data   varbinary (max) NULL,
 UnqId   int  NULL,
 remarks   varchar (500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT  PK_tblFiles  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 id  ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON  PRIMARY 
) ON  PRIMARY  TEXTIMAGE_ON  PRIMARY 

GO
ALTER TABLE  dbo . tblFiles   WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY( UnqId )
REFERENCES  dbo . pmsbl  ( UnqId )
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try by changing Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath)); with

```
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help. Yes it is downloading the file but it is changing the file name and extension also. My file name is aa.txt and it is downloading it as  " upload_aa.txt-1.html "

Comment: file:///C:/Users/BREAKT~1/AppData/Local/Temp/upload_aa.txt-1.html     ----now showing one error -----------DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'.sr1708899235

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>